# String Array only calling method once

Tags: java, console-application

Hello I have an console application where I am attempting to create the game Morris but I have an issue drawing the map after setting a point in the hashmap. I've already confirmed that the value of my point is changing but for some reason the method v is not being called again.

This is the code for the drawing of my array sorry for the horrible looking of my String Array:

```
public abstract class BoardGeometry {
    // Een array van Strings waarmee je het bord kunt tekenen
public static String v(char c) {
    System.out.println(Board.boardHashMap.get(c).getValue());
    return Board.boardHashMap.get(c).getValue();
}

public final static String[] LAYOUT = {
        "" + v('A') + "-----------" + v('B') + "-----------" + v('C') + "       A-----------B-----------C",
        "|           |           |      |           |           |",
        "|   " + v('D') + "-------" + v('E') + "-------" + v('F') + "   |       |   D-------E-------F   |",
        "|   |       |       |   |      |   |       |       |   |",
        "|   |   " + v('G') + "---" + v('H') + "---" + v('I') + "   |   |       |   |   G---H---I   |   |",
        "|   |   |       |   |   |      |   |   |       |   |   |",
        "" + v('J') + "---" + v('K') + "---" + v('L') + "       " + v('M') + "---" + v('N') + "---" + v('O')
                + "     J---K---L       M---N---O",
        "|   |   |       |   |   |      |   |   |       |   |   |",
        "|   |   " + v('P') + "---" + v('Q') + "---" + v('R') + "   |   |       |   |   P---Q---R   |   |",
        "|   |       |       |   |      |   |       |       |   |",
        "|   " + v('S') + "-------" + v('T') + "-------" + v('U') + "   |       |   S-------T-------U   |",
        "|           |           |      |           |           |",
        "" + v('V') + "-----------" + v('W') + "-----------" + v('X') + "       V-----------W-----------X" };
}
```

This is the code I use to draw it:

```
public static void drawMap() {
    for (String s : BoardGeometry.LAYOUT) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

So by putting

```
System.out.println(Board.boardHashMap.get(c).getValue());
```

and using the debug mode I've confirmed that it is going through the v method only once while running not meverytime I call drawMap();

Quite clueless why, my apologies if this is a duplicate question I'm not really sure what to search for and I've been stuck on this for hours till I've been able to pin it down to this.

Comment: since I don't see you actually call the v method, what did you expect?

Comment: in the strong array? wouldn't "" + v('A') + " result in Board.boardHashMap.get('A').getValue();

Comment: `LAYOUT` is assigned a value exactly once, so after that it never changes. If you had a method that returned the same thing that's after the `=`, then it should work though, because then the array is constructed from the updated data.

Comment: Strah sorry, missed that. anyway, drawmap doesn't set Layout, meaning it doesn't call the v method

Comment: Add a redrawMap method that sets String[] s = the whole lot of ugly code

and then LAYOUT = s;
Would that be proper?

Comment: why would you need a s? you can immediately use LAYOUT

Comment: Oh yeah and I just make LAYOUT empty at first so it isn't ugly that I do the exact same thing twice and then always call redrawMap before so it's filled on first use. Thanks so much everyone

Comment: okay Stultuske that's not possible because Array constants can only be used in initializers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you only put a value into LAYOUT once and that value is fixed. You need to recalculate LAYOUT every time before you draw the map otherwise it will stay the same value(map)